# How to publish all flavor variants to maven with Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

Earlier I have used android gradle plugin v2.2.2, now I am migrating to 3.0. The below code publishes(*uploadArchives* task) all my variants to maven without any issues with 2.14.1. But as soon I upgrade to 3.0 nothing is been published. If I remove the *prodcutFlavors*, it publishes the release version of the library to maven properly. Am I missing something? Is something changed in 3.0?

I have read that by default now all variants will be published and publishNonDefault is no more needed. After removing *publishNonDefault* also it does not work.

I am using Gradle 4.1 with plugin 3.0 & Gradle 2.14.1 with plugin 2.2.2

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    publishNonDefault true

    flavorDimensions "app"
    productFlavors{
        apple{

        }
        orange{

        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: mavenLocal().url)
            pom.version = "1.3.7"
            pom.artifactId = "android"
            pom.groupId = "com.example"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I am facing a similar problem.  Although I don't use `productFlavors`, I am expecting `mavenDeployer` to publish three configurations (corresponding to my three build types "debug", "release", and "staging").  But it no longerd does, it only publishes an AAR to Maven for the "release" configuration.

Prior to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.1, the following `mavenDeployer` code *did* publish all three AAR files:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        repository(url:"file://" + "${project.buildDir}/maven/releases")

        pom.groupId = "com.example"
        pom.artifactId = "sdk"
        pom.version = sdkName
    }
}
```

The Gradle code above used to produce the following 3 files published to Maven:

```
sdk/build/maven/releases/com/locuslabs/sdk/develop/sdk-develop-debug.aar 
sdk/build/maven/releases/com/locuslabs/sdk/develop/sdk-develop-staging.aar 
sdk/build/maven/releases/com/locuslabs/sdk/develop/sdk-develop-release.aar
```

However, after upgrading to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.1, it only produces:

```
sdk/build/maven/releases/com/locuslabs/sdk/develop/sdk-develop.aar
```

Notice that there isn't even a suffix of `-release` on the file name even though I'm pretty sure it's the release one.

So far the closest I've come to a solution is documentation for a newer way to publish AAR files to Maven: [android-maven-publish](https://github.com/wupdigital/android-maven-publish).

Background research:

From [Android Libraries: maven vs maven-publish gradle project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469235/android-libraries-maven-vs-maven-publish-gradle-project) I learned that there are two Gradle mechanisms for publishing to Gradle.  Plus there are unofficial Android implementations of those.

**The Maven Plugin: Multiple Artifacts per Project**

An old one which I think you're using because you've specified `apply plugin: 'maven'` which is documented here [The Maven Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html).  To get multiple AAR files output, presumably you would "need need to declare a filter for each artifact you want to publish." but the drawback is "you need to generate multiple POMs" ([Multiple Artifacts per Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sub:multiple_artifacts_per_project)).

**Maven Publishing (new): Publishing multiple modules**

The apparent replacement for [The Maven Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) is a new one, [Maven Publishing (new)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html), which seems to have the ability to publish multiple artifacts as described in [Publishing multiple modules](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#sec:publishing_multiple_modules_to_maven).  Basically it seems like you just need to have multiple method calls in the `publications` block (sorry if I'm using the wrong Gradle/Groovy syntax--it's a confusing language that I wish was never created).

```
publishing {
    publications {
        impl(MavenPublication) {               // for first variant?
            groupId 'org.gradle.sample.impl'
            artifactId 'project2-impl'
            version '2.3'

            from components.java
        }
        api(MavenPublication) {                // for second variant?
            groupId 'org.gradle.sample'
            artifactId 'project2-api'
            version '2'

            artifact apiJar
        }
    }
}

task apiJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName "publishing-api"
    from sourceSets.main.output
    exclude '**/impl/**'
}
```

If that weren't complicated enough, according to [Android Libraries: maven vs maven-publish gradle project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469235/android-libraries-maven-vs-maven-publish-gradle-project), "The above two official plugins don't fully support Android, so there are two community ports."

**Gradle Android Maven plugin (unofficial)**

The documentation at [Gradle Android Maven plugin](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin) doesn't explain how we would output multiple AARs.

**android-maven-publish (unofficial)**

As mentioned above, the documentation at [android-maven-publish](https://github.com/wupdigital/android-maven-publish) looks the most promising because it provides an example to "publish custom variants" which implies that it would solve your problem of publishing all flavor variants.  Here's the example from [android-maven-publish](https://github.com/wupdigital/android-maven-publish):

```
publishing {
    publications {
        android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->

            "maven${variant.name.capitalize()}Aar"(MavenPublication) {
                from components.findByName("android${variant.name.capitalize()}")
                groupId 'digital.wup.test-publish'
                artifactId 'test-publish'
                version "1.0.0-${variant.name}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one! the android-maven-publish as mentioned in its site is no longer needed if your project uses AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) 3.6.0 or newer, as it already supports maven-publish.

Answer (score 2):

The [Maven Publish plugin for Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin) is indeed the way to do this, as mentioned by **htofoya**.

You can either enter all the variants one by one, as shown in the docs, or you can do something like this:

```
afterEvaluate {
    android.libraryVariants.each { variant ->
        // Only consider release
        if (variant.buildType.name != "release") { return }
        publishing.publications.create(variant.name, MavenPublication) {
            from components.findByName(variant.name)
            groupId libraryGroupId
            artifactId "${libraryArtifactId}-${variant.flavorName}"
            version libraryVersion
        }
    }
}
```

The example from [android-maven-publish](https://github.com/wupdigital/android-maven-publish), shown in **Michael Osofsky** answer, is flawed and doesn't produce correct POM files